# How to make a function run only in a certain area (div)

Tags: jquery, image, function, mouse

Thanks to this forum I got my code to work :-) however it needs some finetuning.
The function should only work when the mouse hovers over the image

This is my first try, with the hover function, however something strange is happening when displaying the mouse coordinates.
You can find an (old but working on the entire page) example here: http://designbynine.nl/Test/Test%20pagina%20follow%20mouse04.html (open in Chrome)

```
<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {

    var relativeX           =   Math.ceil(event.pageX/23);
    var currentStep         =   relativeX*-230;

  $(".model").hover(function(){
    $(".model").css("background-position", 0+" "+(currentStep)+"px");
    //just to check what is happeninga
    $("span").text("X: " + event.pageX + ", Y: " + event.pageY)
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.model {
    width: 300px;
    height: 230px;
    background-image: url('sprite.png');
    background-position:0 4000x;
}
</style>

</head>


<body>
<div class="model" style=""></div>
<p>Data <span></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: could you provide a snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ku5cfwp8/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DesignbyNine/the1sjLm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function code with this one :

```
    $(document).mousemove(function(event) {

    var relativeX       =   Math.ceil(event.pageX/123);
    var widthOfElement  =   $(".model").outerWidth();
    var step            =   widthOfElement/300;
    var currentStep     =   Math.ceil(relativeX/step*-231);
    var hovering = false;

  $("span").text("x" + event.pageX + " " + "y" + event.pageY);
  $(".model").css("background-position", 0+" "+(currentStep)+"px");
      if(currentStep < 1)
    {
        currentStep = 1;
    } 
});
```

I changed the function(e) with function(event) :

http://jsfiddle.net/ku5cfwp8/1/

Comment: Thanks, that is a more correct way of writing the code I suppose? I changed it, the code works the same (still only in chrome). I cleaned up the code a bit and tried something with a .hover, but strange things happen now to the X coordinate of the mouse.